# How i can get the list code url which is not indexed on the google search console using the api

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api, google-index, google-indexing-api

How i can get the list code URL that is not indexed on the Google search console using the API? I have the service-account-key.json which only I can use to achieve this. Using PHP or Nodejs.